# Does this mySQL Stored Procedure Work?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, point-in-polygon

I got the following stored procedure from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html

Does this work?

```
CREATE FUNCTION myWithin(p POINT, poly POLYGON) RETURNS INT(1) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE pX DECIMAL(9,6);
DECLARE pY DECIMAL(9,6);
DECLARE ls LINESTRING;
DECLARE poly1 POINT;
DECLARE poly1X DECIMAL(9,6);
DECLARE poly1Y DECIMAL(9,6);
DECLARE poly2 POINT;
DECLARE poly2X DECIMAL(9,6);
DECLARE poly2Y DECIMAL(9,6);
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE result INT(1) DEFAULT 0;
SET pX = X(p);
SET pY = Y(p);
SET ls = ExteriorRing(poly);
SET poly2 = EndPoint(ls);
SET poly2X = X(poly2);
SET poly2Y = Y(poly2);
SET n = NumPoints(ls);
WHILE i<n DO
SET poly1 = PointN(ls, (i+1));
SET poly1X = X(poly1);
SET poly1Y = Y(poly1);
IF ( ( ( ( poly1X <= pX ) && ( pX < poly2X ) ) || ( ( poly2X <= pX ) && ( pX < poly1X ) ) ) && ( pY > ( poly2Y - poly1Y ) * ( pX - poly1X ) / ( poly2X - poly1X ) + poly1Y ) ) THEN
SET result = !result;
END IF;
SET poly2X = poly1X;
SET poly2Y = poly1Y;
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
RETURN result;
End;
```

Usage:

```
SET @point = PointFromText('POINT(5 5)') ;
SET @polygon = PolyFromText('POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10))') ;
SELECT myWithin(@point, @polygon) AS result ;
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin and it blows up when using stored procedures. If this one works, then I'll try to figure out how to call it in php instead.

Thanks,

Laxmidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

CALL myWithin(@point, @polygon);

instead

Comment: Hi e4c5,
Thank you for the answer. I appreciate the help. Sorry for not replying sooner.

Comment: no worries. Glad i could help. all the best with your project.

Answer (score 0):

The example will always return no records unless the polygon is 'complete', for example adding the final `"0 0"` in the `POLYGON` to close off the polygon.

```
SET @polygon = PolyFromText('POLYGON((0 0,10 0,10 10,0 10,**0 0**))') ;
```